# How can I remove a date in the format of ##/##/#### from a string in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file that have strings that start with the date in the form of ##/##/#### and I want to remove the date and keep to work with the rest of the text that is in that line. I have been look at regular expressions but cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: Provide some sample data and what code you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are a good way to go. If they're always in that format, then the expression would be:

```
\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}
```

Note that it doesn't check the validity of the date, i.e., months not 1-12, etc.
an example in python:

```
import re
expr = re.compile('\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}')
line = re.sub(expr, '', input)  # replace all dates with ''
```

This solution would not work if your file contains strings like "145/10/24045", as it would replace it with "15".

Comment: Could also implement re.findall to return a list of all dates as strings.

Answer (score 0):

If every line always has that ten character date date in front, then just cut off the first ten characters of every line with substring.